# How to access files in MacOS after installing using .dmg from tauri build?

Tags: macos, rust, tauri

I'm developing a GUI app using rust tauri. I compiled it for Windows, and Linux, and all works fine. However, on MacOS(both on VM and real machine), my app can't work properly.

Inside my app I create directory, and add jsons into it, and also config.json in the same directory where my app is.

My tauri.conf.json:

```json
{
  "build": {
    "beforeDevCommand": "npm run dev",
    "beforeBuildCommand": "npm run build",
    "devPath": "http://localhost:1420",
    "distDir": "../dist",
    "withGlobalTauri": false
  },
  "package": {
    "productName": "myapp",
    "version": "0.1.2"
  },
  "tauri": {
    "systemTray": {
      "iconPath": "icons/icon.png",
      "iconAsTemplate": true
    },

    "allowlist": {
      "all": true
    },
    "bundle": {
      "active": true,
      "targets": "all",
      "identifier": "com.myapp.dev",
      "icon": ["icons/icon.png", "icons/icon.ico"],
      "resources": ["geoip-only-cn-private.dat", "geoip.dat", "geosite.dat"]
    },
    "security": {
      "csp": null
    },
    "windows": [
      {
        "fullscreen": false,
        "resizable": false,
        "title": "My App",
        "width": 350,
        "height": 650,
        "minWidth": 350,
        "minHeight": 650
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can't read files, I can't write files or directories. I use fs::File::create() and fs::read_to_string() to files in the same directory

I tried to move my app to different location, however it doesn't help. Also I tried to set fs inside allowlist to all: true, but still, my app can't access neither current directory nor any on the computer.

The only thing helps, is to run it from terminal using sudo, but don't want users to do that because some of them don't know how to use terminal, and it will be confusing for them.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with the application architecture if it requires elevated privileges every time it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when you run from a shel(bash, sh, etc.) you always are somewhere, so that your app has curent working dir, but if you run from GUI app gives the default locaiton, which you are not permitted to use. The solution is to store data inside AppData using:

```rust
app<...>.setup(|app| {
            let app_data_dir = resolve_path(
                &app.config(),
                app.package_info(),
                &app.env(),
                "",
                Some(BaseDirectory::AppData),
            )?;
            // And use this path for all
```